# Extracting location from text string

Tags: nlp

I have a problem that may seem trivial on the surface, but I am not sure how to go about solving this problem.

I have a file of 1million lines, each line is a description. In each description, I want to extract the location(City and state if exist). Some locations may be misspelled or incomplete. My goal is to be as accurate as possible.

Here is an example string from my file.

```
wendys-alexandria q25,ALEXANDRIA,,US
wendys-alexandria q25   alexandria   ky,ALEXANDRIA,KY,US
wendys-alexandria q25 alexandria    ky,ALEXANDRIA,KY,US
wendys-alexandria q25 alexandria   ky,ALEXANDRIA,KY,US
wendys-alexandria q25 alexandria ky,ALEXANDRIA,KY,US
wendys-altoona#,ALTOONA,,US
wendys-altoona#       altoona      pa,ALTOONA,PA,US
wendys-altoona#     altoona      pa,ALTOONA,PA,US
wendys-altoona# 000 altoona,ALTOONA,,US
wendys-altoona# 0altoona,ALTOONA,,US
wendys-altoona# altoona      pa,ALTOONA,PA,US
wendys-altoona# altoona pa see all tags,ALTOONA,,US
```

I understand that this problem is Name entity recognization, and I should use "NLP techniques" to solve it. I'm thinking of using Python+Pandas+NLP library.

But if anyone has done similar task before, and can point out a direction for me like which NLP libraries to use, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: Hi I have similar question on what you are trying to do. What is the result you have tried to extract the addresses from a text string?

Comment: Hey, my results were good. Not perfect, but its good enough. I used Google places's API

Comment: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search

Comment: its very straightforward to implement, call the API using the string that you have, and it will return you an address. My code is located here, you can use it as a reference. https://github.com/wxzeng/CreditCardLocationExtractor
Googleplaces.py is where I pass in a cleaned up string and get an address. 

Good luck brother.

Comment: you are planning to extract text from physical business cards?? So that means you have to scan each business cards into a digital file and parse it into text using some OCR program...

Comment: Theres no easy way to do it, unless if all your strings are in the same format.